# How to iterate an array of objects and group the property values by their key name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects named *data*, like so:

```
data = [{"timeslot":"7pm-8pm","Monday":60,"Tuesday":55},
        {"timeslot":"8pm-9pm","Monday":70,"Tuesday":60},
        {"timeslot":"9pm-10pm","Monday":40,"Tuesday":37}]
```

I want to get from this array three new arrays, like so:

```
timeslot = ["7pm-8pm", "8pm-9pm", "9pm-10pm"]
monday   = [60, 70, 40]
tuesdat  = [55, 60, 37]
```

Effectively grouping the data values by the *data* property name to which they belong.

Here is my **Javascript**

```
var timeslot = [];
var monday = [];
var tuesday = [];

var result = {};

// Iterate the objects of the array
for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    // Iterate the properties of the object
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        // Push the value of each property to an array sharing the property's key name
        result[key.toLowerCase()] = [obj[key]];
    });
}

console.log(result.timeslot, result.monday, result.tuesday);
```

This returns

```
["9pm-10pm"] [40] [37]
```

These are the property values of *data*'s third and final object.
It appears that the code inside the forEach is replacing the previous element of the new array with the current element. The new arrays each contain only one element, instead of the desired three.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that, while you are iterating over the `keys` array, you are replacing the previous value each time here

```
result[key.toLowerCase()] = [obj[key]];  // This is replacing the existing value
```

To add a new entry to an array, you can use [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method as shown below :

```
result[key.toLowerCase()].push([obj[key]]);
```

```js
var data = [{"timeslot":"7pm-8pm","Monday":60,"Tuesday":55},{"timeslot":"8pm-9pm","Monday":70,"Tuesday":60},{"timeslot":"9pm-10pm","Monday":40,"Tuesday":37}];

var result = {}; 

data.map(function (each) {
  Object.keys(each).map(function (key){
    result[key] = result[key] || [];
    result[key].push(each[key]);
  });

});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basicall you are overwiting the last result with a new array

```
result[key.toLowerCase()] = [obj[key]];
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^        ^
```

But you need only one array for a key and the push the actual value, like

```
result[key] = result[key] || []; // create array, if not exist
result[key].push(o[k]);          // push value
```

Working code:

```js
var data = [{ timeslot: "7pm-8pm", Monday: 60, Tuesday: 55 }, { timeslot: "8pm-9pm", Monday: 70, Tuesday: 60}, { timeslot: "9pm-10pm", Monday: 40, Tuesday: 37 }],
    result = {};

data.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        var key = k.toLowerCase();
        result[key] = result[key] || [];
        result[key].push(o[k]);
    });
});

console.log(result);
```