# Pivot a Javascript array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help restructuring this Array of Objects in JavaScript.  This is what my current array looks like

```json
[
  {
    "StatusYear": 2018,
    "Requests": 55,
    "Approved": 33,
    "NotApproved": 22,
    "IP": 22,
    "ELA": 0,
    "CapAvoid": 0
  },
  {
    "StatusYear": 2019,
    "Requests": 611,
    "Approved": 422,
    "NotApproved": 189,
    "IP": 167,
    "ELA": 0,
    "CapAvoid": 4851118
  },
  {
    "StatusYear": 2020,
    "Requests": 1166,
    "Approved": 724,
    "NotApproved": 217,
    "IP": 411,
    "ELA": 219,
    "CapAvoid": 16646386
  }
]
```

and I need some form like this i believe

```js
[
  { Requests: [55, 611, 1166] },
  { Approved: [33, 422, 724] },
  { NotApproved: [22, 189, 217] },
  ...etc
]
```

Needless to say my efforts have come up short

Edit:  The reason I need a different structure is I've got to create a table and the original data will have an addition object next year (i.e. StatusYear 2021).  My table structure needs to look like so

This is excel but it will be a table in react just looks similar

[image: Table Example]

I've tried to pivot it like so and gotten an array with the values but I can't figure out how to make an array of objects like above

```
const transpose = (data) => {
  return Object.keys(data[0]).map((x) => data.map((y) => y[x]));
};
```

my results of the transpose ended up looking like so.  I don't know how to create objects in the array for each unique key

```
[2018,2019,2020,55,611,1166,33,422,724,22,189,217,22,167,411,0,0,219,0,4851118,16646386]
```

Comment: @Spruce How on earth is that going to help?

Comment: [How to iterate an array of objects and group the property values by their key name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592542) This is not an exact duplicate but you get the idea

Comment: Nonetheless please show your efforts.

Comment: "need some form like this i believe" – how come "I believe"? Shouldn't you _know_ what you want? IOW, what is it you're trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: Are you sure you want array of objects or a single object with each of the params as an array?

Answer (score 0):

**Two Solutions**

Are you sure you want array of objects or a single object with each of the params as an array?

**Solution 1 (Better one, IMHO)**

Because, if it was the former, you can do something like this using `reduce()` function:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    StatusYear: 2018,
    Requests: 55,
    Approved: 33,
    NotApproved: 22,
    IP: 22,
    ELA: 0,
    CapAvoid: 0
  },
  {
    StatusYear: 2019,
    Requests: 611,
    Approved: 422,
    NotApproved: 189,
    IP: 167,
    ELA: 0,
    CapAvoid: 4851118
  },
  {
    StatusYear: 2020,
    Requests: 1166,
    Approved: 724,
    NotApproved: 217,
    IP: 411,
    ELA: 219,
    CapAvoid: 16646386
  }
];

const fin = arr.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => {
    const p = acc;
    p.Requests.push(cur.Requests);
    p.Approved.push(cur.Approved);
    p.NotApproved.push(cur.NotApproved);
    p.StatusYear.push(cur.StatusYear);
    p.IP.push(cur.IP);
    p.ELA.push(cur.ELA);
    p.CapAvoid.push(cur.CapAvoid);
    return p;
  },
  {
    Requests: [],
    Approved: [],
    NotApproved: [],
    StatusYear: [],
    IP: [],
    ELA: [],
    CapAvoid: []
  }
);
console.log(fin);
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Requests": [55, 611, 1166],
  "Approved": [33, 422, 724],
  "NotApproved": [22, 189, 217],
  "StatusYear": [2018, 2019, 2020],
  "IP": [22, 167, 411],
  "ELA": [0, 0, 219],
  "CapAvoid": [0, 4851118, 16646386]
}
```

**Solution 2 (Your Solution)**

If you want something like the one you asked, you can make the above array of objects into array of object arrays.

```js
const arr = [{
    StatusYear: 2018,
    Requests: 55,
    Approved: 33,
    NotApproved: 22,
    IP: 22,
    ELA: 0,
    CapAvoid: 0
  },
  {
    StatusYear: 2019,
    Requests: 611,
    Approved: 422,
    NotApproved: 189,
    IP: 167,
    ELA: 0,
    CapAvoid: 4851118
  },
  {
    StatusYear: 2020,
    Requests: 1166,
    Approved: 724,
    NotApproved: 217,
    IP: 411,
    ELA: 219,
    CapAvoid: 16646386
  }
];

const fin = arr.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => {
    const p = acc;
    p.Requests.push(cur.Requests);
    p.Approved.push(cur.Approved);
    p.NotApproved.push(cur.NotApproved);
    p.StatusYear.push(cur.StatusYear);
    p.IP.push(cur.IP);
    p.ELA.push(cur.ELA);
    p.CapAvoid.push(cur.CapAvoid);
    return p;
  }, {
    Requests: [],
    Approved: [],
    NotApproved: [],
    StatusYear: [],
    IP: [],
    ELA: [],
    CapAvoid: []
  }
);

console.log(Object.keys(fin).map(key => ({
  [key]: fin[key]
})));
```

Output:

```json
[
  { "Requests": [55, 611, 1166] },
  { "Approved": [33, 422, 724] },
  { "NotApproved": [22, 189, 217] },
  { "StatusYear": [2018, 2019, 2020] },
  { "IP": [22, 167, 411] },
  { "ELA": [0, 0, 219] },
  { "CapAvoid": [0, 4851118, 16646386] }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I will assume that all the objects have the exact same properties, no more and no less.

You can iterate over the existing properties of the first item and create your resulting array from there, like so :

```js
const source = [{
    "StatusYear": 2018,
    "Requests": 55,
    "Approved": 33,
    "NotApproved": 22,
    "IP": 22,
    "ELA": 0,
    "CapAvoid": 0
  },
  {
    "StatusYear": 2019,
    "Requests": 611,
    "Approved": 422,
    "NotApproved": 189,
    "IP": 167,
    "ELA": 0,
    "CapAvoid": 4851118
  },
  {
    "StatusYear": 2020,
    "Requests": 1166,
    "Approved": 724,
    "NotApproved": 217,
    "IP": 411,
    "ELA": 219,
    "CapAvoid": 16646386
  }
]

const result = []

Object.keys(source[0]).forEach(key => {
  result.push({
    [key]: source.map(item => item[key])
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You could use `map` on the keys and remove a step: `const result = Object.keys(source[0]).map(key => ({ [key]: source.map(item => item[key])  }) )`